# How to tab to fieldset, expand, and also change class if not all fields are populated?

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion, legend, fieldset

I have a system where forms are built dynamically, and some may contain 100+ questions.  Each of these questions contain around 3 different child-questions/fields for responses.  The child-questions are wrapped in a div: `.dfcolumns` that is collapsed on page load, then I'm using jquery toggle to expand them when the question/legend is clicked.

**I need to accomplish two more things here:**

1. Tab to the next fieldset and have it open. (would be awesome to have only one open at a time, like an accordion)
2. Change the class of a fieldset/legend if all child fields are populated (I'm not looking for basic form validation here, as I want this to happen during the process, not when hitting submit).

Basically for a better user experience, I'd like to let he user have the ability to tab through the questions, and know which questions they've completed along the way.

**The html:**

```
<div class="dform">
<div class="dform_element">
    <div class="dform_container">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>1. Question/Toggle Trigger</legend>
            <div class="dfcolumns">
                *a bunch of field types here…
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dform_element">
    <div class="dform_container">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>2. Question/Toggle Trigger</legend>
            <div class="dfcolumns">
            <div class="dfcolumns">
                *a bunch of field types here…
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:** `.dfcolumns {display: none;}`

**The toggle function:**

```
    $(function(){
    $("legend").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().find(".dfcolumns").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Are either of these other two goals even possible?  And if so, any ideas on how I would go about it?

Thanks so much for any input!

Comment: all is possible but you may want to consider looking at form wizard plugins. Tab in visible form will go to next field, but if field is hidden it gets bypassed so have to write code to handle that. It is quite likely you can find a plugin that has a lot of the functionality you need with a lot less manual coding required

Answer (score 0):

i have come with simple solution using jquery :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>

<form class="fieldset-tabs">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Tab 1</legend>
        **Tab 1 Cont**
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Tab 2</legend>
        **Tab Cont 2**
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

and the javascript is :

```
jquery(function(){
        $('.fieldset-tabs fieldset').each(function (index) {
            var text = $(this).addClass('tab tab-'+index).find('legend').text() ;
            $('.nav.nav-tabs').append('<li><a href="#" data-toggle=".tab-'+index+'">'+text+'</a></li>') ;
        });
        $('.nav.nav-tabs li a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault() ;
            var $a = $(this);
            var $li =  $a.parent().addClass('active');
            $('.nav.nav-tabs li').not($li).removeClass('active');
            $('.fieldset-tabs fieldset.tab').not($a.data('toggle')).hide();
            $($a.data('toggle')).show();
        }).eq(0).trigger('click') ;
    });
```